# opencv 3.0 beta windows distribution doesn't have viz module

Tags: c++, opencv

I downloaded and installed opencv beta windows binary, but it seems it doesn't have viz module.

Am I right or should I do something to have viz module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build VTK 6.1 ([download](http://www.vtk.org/files/release/6.1/VTK-6.1.0.zip)) using CMake 2.8.x with shared libs turned off. VTK needs to be build as static library so it can be used to link to opencv with the VIZ module.

Build opencv with the viz module turned on using the src and build folders for vtk.

I build the latest 64bit version with VIZ, Contrib and CUDA modules with AVX and SSE ([download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvprebuilt/)), you should be able to pick it up from here. The readme contains the build config.